# Handle checkbox input in x-axis label with Highcharts and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

In my application I need to be able to display some data and select one or more of the categories. The categories are the x-axis labels and I've adapted one of the Highcharts examples to include a checkbox input for each x-axis label.

See https://codepen.io/kdbruin/pen/JNRgqa for a working example when not using AngularJS.

When I change the label formatter to

```
formatter: function() {
  return "<input type='checkbox' onchange='onChange(\"" + this.value + "\")'> " + this.value;;
}
```

the event is ignored.

So how can I handle the `onchange` event on the input using a function from the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Your formatter callback is called outside the controller's scope so it does not have access to `onChange()`. Possible workaround to this might be getting the scope from the dom element.

```
 formatter: function() {
      var query = "[ng-controller=appCtrl]";
      return "<input type='checkbox' onchange='angular.element(document.querySelector(\"" + query + "\")).scope().onChange(\"" + this.value + "\")'>" + this.value;
    }
```

example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWBNOV?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As the actual code is a lot more complex it is not easy to use this but it has given me some handles on where to look for possible solutions.